# Style menu item class only when parents have the same class

Tags: jquery, html, css, sidebar

I have a side bar navigation menu in my website, I have created it with a plugin called [tendina](https://iprignano.github.io/tendina/) , suppose my menu has the following structure

```
-Menu Main 1
--Main-1 Sub-1
-Menu Main 2
-- Main-2 Sub-1
---Main-2 Sub-1 Sub-1
---Main-2 Sub-1 Sub-2
```

when I select any child menu the plugin will mark all its parents as selected with a css class. so I can't style the selected item only, that is suppose I am **clicked** Main-2 Sub-2 Sub-2 link then plugin will add class for its parent item Main-2 Sub-1 and Menu Main 2.how can I then apply for the selected menu only, is there anyway to style without using any script. please help me.

**EDIT**

*HTML Code*

```
 <li class="desig-menu">
          <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink16" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#"  CssClass="desig-nav">Master<span class="caret left-sm-caret"></span></asp:HyperLink>
          <ul  class="dropdown-level-1">
            <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink17" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#">Accounts<span class="caret left-sm-caret"></span>    </asp:HyperLink>
                <ul  class="dropdown-level-2">
                    <li>
                      <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink18" CssClass="account-grp-page-link"  runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/master/accounts/account_group.aspx">Account Group</asp:HyperLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink37" CssClass="account-ledger-page-link"  runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/master/accounts/account_ledger.aspx">Account Ledger</asp:HyperLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink38" CssClass="fin-year-page-link"  runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/master/accounts/financial_year.aspx">financial Year </asp:HyperLink>
                    </li>
                 </ul>
                  <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink39" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#">Services<span class="caret left-sm-caret"></span>    </asp:HyperLink>
                <ul  class="dropdown-level-2">
                    <li>
                      <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink40" CssClass="category-page-link"  runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/master/service/service_category.aspx">Service Category</asp:HyperLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink41" CssClass="service-page-link"  runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/master/service/service.aspx">Service</asp:HyperLink>
                    </li>
                 </ul>
            </li>
              <li><asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink47" runat="server" CssClass="supplier-page-link" NavigateUrl="~/master/supplier_form.aspx">Supplier</asp:HyperLink>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>
```

Comment: Provide the html for your menu.

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt please have a look, I cant include all the menu because it is too lengthy

Answer (score 0):

Try this I suggest, execute the following when your anchor tag inside li tag is clicked:

```
var root=false;
var curr = this;
while(root==false) {
  if($(curr).parent().parent().parent().hasClass("desig-menu")==false) {
    $(curr).parent().parent().parent().addClass("classtoadd");
    curr=$(curr).parent().parent();
  }
  else {
    root=true;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Brijesf is there any way without using script ?

Comment: How can it be possible without script??